# elastic count average score in all documents and use it in max_score

Tags: elasticsearch

Can i make such a query in which i could count average or approximately close to max score in all docs and use it for filtering docs?

1. Count average hightest score, save it somewhere.
2. Use this value in "max_score" field in query to filter inaccurate search results.

I've tried to use aggregation function to count such score but got null:
Request:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "average_score": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
     ...
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "average_score": {
      "value": null
    }
  }
}
```